# DropDownList with anchor tag elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am new to .net programming and perhaps what I am trying to do is relatively simple but I couldn't find any useful example until now.

I want to generate anchor elements into a DropDownList. I have the following code in asp.net:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the code behind(c#), I want to interrogate the database (the result returns an url, description and title) and fill in the DropDownList with the following:

```
<a href="url">Title description</a>
```

I add the db results to the DropDownList like this:

```
while (reader){
    list.Add("<a href='" + url + "'> " + title +" "+  description+"</a>");
}
this.DropDownList1.DataSource = list;

this.DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

But it is showing the whole line into the DropDownList:

```
"<a href='" + url + "'> " + title +" "+  description+"</a>"
```

,where url, title and description are interpreted, and the anchor tag is appearing as well.

I want to display only: title description. And on selected, I want to redirect the user to the url indicated in href attribute.

Is it possible to do this in asp.net and c#? Can anyone help me with some example or tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of trying to bring anchor tags in your dropdown, you should show the normal select element with the url as the `value` of ***OPTION***. So your HTML markup will look like this

```
<SELECT id="SomeSelect">
  <OPTION value="http://www.google.com">Google</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="http://www.aol.com">AOL</OPTION>
  <OPTION value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Now use javascript to listen for the `change` event of the dropdown and get the selected item's `value` attribute's value and use that to navigate. The below code sample does that assuming you have jQuery library loaded to your page.

```
$(function(){

  $("#SomeSelect").change(function(e){
     var selectedUrl=$(this).val();
     window.location.href=selectedUrl;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DropDownList` isn't really designed to do what you are asking of it. I would suggest that you update your code to bind the URL to the `value` attribute of the `DropDownList` and then the description/title as the `text` element.

e.g.

```
while (reader){
    // read about the ListItem here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h.aspx
    list.add(new ListItem(title + " " + description, url));
}
```

Then add a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to the control. So in your Page Load add;

```
this.DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged += DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Then create a method to handle this;

```
public void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Redirect(this.DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
```